# Update query laravel return false result and nothing error show why?

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working with laravel project, and i have an issue that is update query result return false value if i update with the same data, how to solve this? do i have to validate first before run the query and send a notification that the data is the same?
well this is my codes

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $kamar_id    = $request->input('kamar_id');
    $title       = $request->input('title');
    $content     = $request->input('content');
    $keyword     = $request->input('keyword');
    $description = $request->input('description');
    $prolog      = $request->input('prolog');
    $path        = $request->input('path');
    $sort        = $request->input('sort');
    $status      = $request->input('status');
    $type        = $request->input('type');
    $user_id     = $request->input('user_id');

    if (empty($request->input('path'))) {
        $path = serialize(array('data/def.png'));
    }else{
        $path = serialize(explode(',', $request->input('path')));
    }

    $data = array('title' => $title,
                  'content' => $content,
                  'keyword' => $keyword,
                  'description' => $description,
                  'prolog' => $prolog,
                  'path' => $path,
                  'sort' => $sort,
                  'status' => $status,
                  'type' => $type,
                  'user_id' => $user_id);
    // echo($kamar_id);
    $update = Kamar::where('kamar_id',$kamar_id)->update($data);
    if ($update) {
        $response['status'] = 1;
    }else{
        $response['status'] = 0;
    }

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

thanks for helping me

Comment: Update returns false if nothing is updated in the database. If you want to catch any errors with the query, use `try` and `catch` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Eloquent Update method returns **true** if anything updated in database from your query and return **false** if nothing is updated in database from your query.
refer:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 0):

!nullTry

```
 $update = Kamar::where('kamar_id','=',$kamar_id)->first();

 if (!null($update)) 
 {
   $update->title = $title;
   $update->content = $content;
   $update->keyword = $keyword;
   $update->description = $description;
   $update->prolog = $prolog;
   $update->path = $path;
   $update->sort = $sort;
   $update->status = $status;
   $update->type = $type;
   $update->user_id = $user_id;
   $update->save();
   $response['status'] = 1;
 }
 else
 {
   $response['status'] = 0;
 }
```

Comment: your code is working, but there is an error so change if content with $update!=NULL, it works but when a query update runs it gets error and says SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' thanks for the code anyway

Comment: Check whether the `Kamar` has the primary key `kamar_id` or `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this**

```
$kamarObj = new Kamar();
$kamarData = $kamarObj->find($kamar_id);

$result = $kamarData->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force `updated_at` column to be updated (or you can create this column if you don't have). So the query will be always updated.